# Hi,How can I add a photo to a web page with Django?

Tags: html, django, image, forms, django-models

how can I create this feature so that the user can choose a photo for a product from within the system or enter its URL? This image should be added to the product list along with other information.

This is my code. The page loads, but it doesn't do anything special and it doesn't have the URL box either.

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h2 id="h2">Create List</h2>

    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h3 id="h3">Title:</h3>
        <input id="input" placeholder="Title" type="text" name="createlist_title"/>

        <h3 id="h3">Category:</h3>
        <input id="input" placeholder="Category" type="text" name="category"/>
        
        <h3 id="h3">Description:</h3>
        <textarea id="input" placeholder="Description"  type="text" name="createlist_description">
        </textarea>
        
        <h3 id="h3">Firstprice:</h3>
        <input id="input" placeholder="first_price" type="number" name="createlist_price"/>
        
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <h3 id="h3"> Upload image:</h3>
            <input id="input" type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload">
            <input id="button2" type="submit" value="upload">
        </form>``

        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{%url "upload_image" %}">
            <h3 id="h3"> Upload image with URL:</h3>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button id="button2" type="submit">Upload</button>
        </form>
            
        <button id="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
        
    </form>
```

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your template the "models.py" file should be something like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    first_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_images/', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title
```

you can use "forms.py" to create product and upload image, to do that first create a file named "forms.py" where you "models.py" is and in that file:

```
from django import forms

class ProductForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    first_price = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    image_upload = forms.ImageField(required=False)  # For local file upload
    image_url = forms.URLField(required=False)  # For URL-based image upload
```

then your "views.py" file should be like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import ProductForm
from .models import Product

def create_product(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            category = form.cleaned_data['category']
            description = form.cleaned_data['description']
            first_price = form.cleaned_data['first_price']
            image_upload = form.cleaned_data['image_upload']
            image_url = form.cleaned_data['image_url']

            product = Product(
                title=title,
                category=category,
                description=description,
                first_price=first_price,
            )

            if image_upload:
                product.image = image_upload
            elif image_url:
                product.image = image_url

            product.save()

            # you can redirect to the product list or detail page like this:
            # return redirect('product_list') 

    else:
        form = ProductForm()

    return render(request, 'upload/create_product.html', {'form': form}) # I have named the app "upload" you should use your own app name
```

and "create_product.html" file should be something like this:

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
    <h2 id="h2">Create List</h2>

    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button id="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

in order to work with images you should install "Pillow" Library:

```
pip install Pillow
```

and finally you should add this in your "settings.py" file to save the images:

```
import os
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

I hope this helps you.